# Select Tag Helper not Rendering Attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, tag-helpers

I'm trying to generate a `select` using the tag helpers in ASP.NET Core, but it seems to struggle with "dynamic" attributes. For example, if I have this:

```
//  f is some model

var required = f.IsRequired ? "required" : string.Empty;// true for example
var multiple = f.IsMultiple ? "multiple" : string.Empty;// true for example

<select asp-items="@f.SelectItems" @multiple @required>
</select>
```

I expect to get:

```html
<select multiple required>
    <option></option>
    ...
</select>
```

But instead I get:

```html
<select>
    <option></option>
    ...
</select>
```

Is there some way to make my expectation happen?

Comment: You can just set `required` and `multiple` to `true` or `false` and then use `multiple="@multiple" required="@required"`.

Comment: Wow, didn't expect it to be that simple, but it was. Could you post it as answer? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, this doesn't seem quite right. In `false` situations a `required="False"` attribute is rendered, which is simply treated as `required` and forces a browser warning on fields that shouldn't be required.

Comment: I believe you can fix that by using `null` instead of `false`.

Comment: That was it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is really from Kirk, but I'll summarize it.

For the `required` and `multiple` attributes to be rendered they must have a value of `true` and for them *not* to be rendered they must have a value of `null`.